# Is the value group of an algebraically closed valued field divisible?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, model-theory, valuation-theory

Is the value group of an algebraically closed valued field divisible? Since Every existentially closed abelian group is divisible, I'm trying to show the value group is existentially closed but I don't know how... Even I don't know if the claim holds or not...

Comment: Is the value group of the $p$-adic numbers $\Bbb Q_p$ divisible?

Comment: So Sorry I forgot to mention ... I meant an algebraically closed valued field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $b$ is a root of $x^n-a$, then $n\cdot v(b) = v(a)$.